# My php script is unable to send email on my vps (using PHPMailer)

Tags: php, smtp, phpmailer, vps

I've copied the script to my shared host provider and it worked. I also ran the script in my local computer and it also worked. Something that I think worthy mentioning is that the email server is from the shared host provider and my application is running on a vps (I changed only the dns records relating to connecting to my web site through a web browser).

```
use PHPMailer;
       $mail = new PHPMailer;



$mail->isSMTP(); 
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;  
$mail->SMTPDebug = 1;  
$mail->Host = 'smtp.uhsevico.com';
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;
$mail->Username = "adm@mydomain.com.br";
$mail->Password = "mypassoword";
//$mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';  

$mail->Port = 587;                                  

$mail->setFrom('sender@mydomain.com.br', 'contato imotur');
mail->addAddress('receiver@yahoo.com', 'Diego Alves');    


$mail->Subject = 'Here is the subject';


$mail->Body    = "ImoTur no contato das atividades";
//$mail->AltBody = 'This is the body in plain text for non-HTML mail          clients';

if(!$mail->send()) {
echo 'Message could not be sent.';
echo 'Mailer Error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
} else {
echo 'Message has been sent';
}
```

The Error:

2017-02-21 18:30:03 SMTP ERROR: Failed to connect to server: Connection timed out (110) 2017-02-21 18:30:03 SMTP connect() failed. https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting Message could not be sent.Mailer Error: SMTP connect() failed. https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting

Comment: Diagnosing problems like this is exactly what is described in the troubleshooting guide that you ignored the link to.

Comment: How can you want someone that never wrote a code for sending email before troubleshoot email sending. The troubleshoot guide is too much for me!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a similar problem when I was getting mail working on a university VPS. They had specific configurations where all outgoing mail had to be forward to. I had my own mail server installed on my VPS, then changed the configurations so all mail was sent to the university servers. I'd contact your hosting provider to see if they have some specific configurations you need on your VPS.

Comment: Oh yeah! After two days modifying my code and blaming myself I've figured that my vps blocks the port 587 for new accounts or accounts that show suspicius behavior or something like that!

Comment: You showed me the right direction. I would never have guessed that it was the hosting provider.

Comment: Glad you figured it out!

Comment: You might have guessed it was your hosting provider if you had read the troubleshooting guide, since that's exactly the explanation it gives for the error you were seeing...